# Coldfusion: QueryNew and auto increment?

Tags: coldfusion, auto-increment

Is there a possiblity to add the "auto_increment" attribute to QueryNew() in Coldfusion?
I want to simulate a database, so I need a primary key, which I refer to.
My goal is an easy navigation with nav_id and nav_pid (parent id).

If there is no easy solution I'll do it with a loop or just add it as follow:

```
<cfset querySetCell(nav, "nav_id", 1) />
```

thx for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, there is no auto-increment attribute that could be set for a querycolumn in a newly created queryobject: https://helpx.adobe.com/de/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/querynew.html

So you must go with a loop and create your query:

```
 <CFLOOP from="1" to="5" index="i">
    <cfset querySetCell(nav, "nav_id", i) />
 </CFLOOP>
```